# QThread execution freezes my GUI

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm new to multithread programming. I wrote this simple multi thread program with Qt. But when I run this program it freezes my GUI and when I click inside my widow, it responds that your program is not responding .
Here is my widget class. My thread starts to count an integer number and emits it when this number is dividable by 1000. In my widget simply I catch this number with signal-slot mechanism and show it in a label and a progress bar.

```
   Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MyThread *th = new MyThread;
    connect( th, SIGNAL(num(int)), this, SLOT(setNum(int)));
    th->start();
}


void Widget::setNum(int n)
{
    ui->label->setNum( n);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(n%101);
}
```

and here is my thread run() function :

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        if( i % 1000 == 0)
            emit num(i);
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: This part looks fine. Are you at some point waiting for the thread to finish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with your thread code producing an event storm. The loop counts very fast -- so fast, that the fact that you emit a signal every 1000 iterations is pretty much immaterial. On modern CPUs, doing a 1000 integer divisions takes on the order of 10 microseconds IIRC. If the loop was the only limiting factor, you'd be emitting signals at a peak rate of about 100,000 per second. This is not the case because the performance is limited by other factors, which we shall discuss below.

Let's understand what happens when you emit signals in a different thread from where the receiver `QObject` lives. The signals are packaged in a `QMetaCallEvent` and posted to the event queue of the receiving thread. An event loop running in the receiving thread -- here, the GUI thread -- acts on those events using an instance of `QAbstractEventDispatcher`. Each `QMetaCallEvent` results in a call to the connected slot.

The access to the event queue of the receiving GUI thread is serialized by a `QMutex`. On Qt 4.8 and newer, the QMutex implementation got a nice speedup, so the fact that each signal emission results in locking of the queue mutex is not likely to be a problem. Alas, the events need to be allocated on the heap in the worker thread, and then deallocated in the GUI thread. Many heap allocators perform quite poorly when this happens in quick succession if the threads happen to execute on different cores.

The biggest problem comes in the GUI thread. There seems to be a bunch of hidden O(n^2) complexity algorithms! The event loop has to process 10,000 events. Those events will be most likely delivered very quickly and end up in a contiguous block in the event queue. The event loop will have to deal with all of them before it can process further events. A lot of expensive operations happen when you invoke your slot. Not only is the `QMetaCallEvent` deallocated from the heap, but the label schedules an `update()` (repaint), and this internally posts a compressible event to the event queue. Compressible event posting has to, in worst case, iterate over entire event queue. That's one potential O(n^2) complexity action. Another such action, probably more important in practice, is the progressbar's `setValue` internally calling `QApplication::processEvents()`. This can, recursively call your slot to deliver the subsequent signal from the event queue. You're doing way more work than you think you are, and this locks up the GUI thread.

Instrument your slot and see if it's called recursively. A quick-and-dirty way of doing it is

```
void Widget::setNum(int n)
{
  static int level = 0, maxLevel = 0;
  level ++;
  maxLevel = qMax(level, maxLevel);
  ui->label->setNum( n);
  ui->progressBar->setValue(n%101);
  if (level > 1 && level == maxLevel-1) {
    qDebug("setNum recursed up to level %d", maxLevel);
  }
  level --;
}
```

What is freezing your GUI thread is not QThread's execution, but the huge amount of work you make the GUI thread do. Even if your code looks innocuous.

#### Side Note on processEvents and Run-to-Completion Code

I think it was a very bad idea to have `QProgressBar::setValue` invoke `processEvents()`. It only encourages the broken way people code things (continuously running code instead of short run-to-completion code). Since the `processEvents()` call can recurse into the caller, `setValue` becomes a persona-non-grata, and possibly quite dangerous.

If one wants to code in continuous style yet keep the run-to-completion semantics, there are ways of dealing with that in C++. One is just by leveraging the preprocessor, for example code see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842585/1329652).

Another way is to use [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) to get the C++ compiler to generate the code you want. You may want to leverage a template library here -- [Boost spirit](http://www.amergerzic.com/post/ExpressionTemplates.aspx) has a decent starting point of an implementation that can be reused even though you're not writing a parser.

The [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) also tackles the problem of how to write sequential style code yet have it run as short run-to-completion fragments. They resort to specifying the flow of control in XML. There's apparently no direct way of reusing standard C# syntax. They only provide it as a data structure, a-la JSON. It'd be simple enough to implement both XML and code-based WF in Qt, if one wanted to. All that in spite of .NET and C# providing ample support for programmatic generation of code...

Answer (score 2):

The way you implemented your thread, it does not have its own event loop (because it does not call `exec()`). I'm not sure if your code within `run()` is actually executed within your thread or within the GUI thread.

Usually you should not subclass `QThread`. You probably did so because you read the Qt Documentation which unfortunately still recommends subclassing `QThread` - even though the developers long ago wrote [a blog entry](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) stating that you should not subclass `QThread`. Unfortunately, they still haven't updated the documentation appropriately.

I recommend reading ["You're doing it wrong"](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) on Qt Blog and then use the [answer by "Kari"](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/#comment-7925) as an example of how to set up a basic multi-threaded system.

Comment: The thread, as written, does not run its event loop, and that's bad style, but of course the `run()` method is executed within the thread -- that's what it's for! I agree with the other points.

Comment: Unfortunately, after reading that blog post - he points to "the best resource ... right now" which goes to a dead link. After a bunch of digging yesterday, we came across this excellent resource which hopefully goes some way to replacing the missing article: https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

Answer (score 0):

`But when I run this program it freezes my GUI and when I click inside my window,
it responds that your program is not responding.`

Yes because IMO you're doing **too much work in thread** that it **exhausts CPU**. Generally `program is not responding` message pops up when **process** show no progress in handling application event queue requests. In your case this happens.

So in this case you should find a way to divide the work. Just for the sake of example say, thread runs in chunks of **100** and repeat the thread till it completes **10000000**.

Also you should have look at `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` when you're performing a lengthy operation.

Comment: Sorry but this is some quite incorrect guesswork. The CPU exhaustion in the worker thread is not an issue. The issue is with what happens in the GUI thread. The `processEvents()` method is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: Actually, I misspoke: the `processEvents()` method *is* relevant, but in quite a different way. It is indirectly invoked in the GUI thread, by the `setValue` method of progressbar, and there it's quite counterproductive, heck, it may exhaust the stack if there's enough events posted. What you want is precisely the opposite of what you suggest: the `processEvents()` should *not* be called. Besides, calling it in the worker thread in this example would be entirely pointless. Since there are no events delivered to the worker thread's event queue, the call would be a no-op.