# Updating QtGui elements from python

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I wrote a small application using QT and Python.
I Press a button, a wait for serial input for 5 seconds. I have few labels
which I want to update e.g., when I press button it should change to 'starting reading' and when I return it should change to 'reading done'. I use
a simple thread which calls processEvents but it does not gets updated and when read function finishes I see the last label change.

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    print 'myWindow'
    super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('test1.ui', self)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()'), self.buttonStartClicked)
    self.show()



  def buttonStartClicked(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target = self.update_gui, args = ())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    self.label.setText('Starting Test')
    response = sRS232_Con.read()
    #QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
    self.label.setText('Ending Test')


  def update_gui(self):
    while True :
      QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
      print 'update'
      time.sleep(1)


def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: why is #QtGui.QApplication.processEvents() in comment?

Comment: Because I want to call processEvents at one central point, like in a separate thread which could update multiple widgets.

Comment: First of all: forget about multiple threads. They are unnecessary for your application. Second of all, you should never have to call `processEvents` - that you do indicates that your design is broken. `app.exec_` does all the event processing. You then need to use `QStateMachine` to define the states your application is in, and how it should react to state changes. For inspiration in C++, see e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32595398/1329652).

Answer (score 0):

In Qt any `QObject` that is managed by some event loop should not be touch by other thread (at least without any protection).

If for some reason you cannot use `QSerialPort` library that provides asynchronous API for serial port it is possible to use `QThread` for separate thread managed by Qt signals and slots.

Events for QtGui are dispatched by the main thread (insided of the loop `app.exec_()`).
Another `QThread` can work with serial port and it can emit signals on `'Starting Test'` and on `'Ending Test'`. Those signals can be connected to `MyWindow` slots that are able to update UI in the main thread.