# Distorted answers on serial port

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

So.. I am using this code to read some informations from a powertek pa4400a, and sometimes I can read it without any problems but sometimes I'm getting weird answers. I'm not even able to understand what does characters mean.

```
QSerialPort asd;
asd.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud19200);
asd.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
asd.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
asd.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
asd.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
asd.setPortName("ttyUSB0");
asd.open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
asd.write(com);
asd.waitForReadyRead(10000);
QString ans = asd.readAll();
```

The ans string should look like this:

```
"00.00E+0; 00.00E+0;+00.00E+0; 00.00E+0; 000:00:00;<<END OF DATA>>"
```

But I am getting things like this:

```
"\xFB"
```

Or any other stuff that's not right.

I did get the right answer a lot of times but something happened and I can't read the information anymore.

Comment: You're not doing anything obviously wrong, but I have no good experience with pseudo-synchronous code that uses any `waitForXxx` methods. See if you could implement your command-and-response system using the approach from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32595398/1329652), perhaps. What platform is this on?

Comment: Windows, but the problem was at flow control. I switched to HardwareControl and now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here it was that the machine I was sending commands to was using HardwareControl, but I used NoFlowControl, and that messed up my answers.