# Qt 5.6 - QNetworkReply finished() never called

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to do a simple GET request using QNetworkReply but finished() never get's called, here is my code

```
QtTest::QtTest(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){
  ui.setupUi(this);

  auto network_access_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  auto reply = network_access_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")));
  connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(download_finished()));


qDebug() << "Started";

}

void QtTest::download_finished() {

  qDebug() << "Finished";

}
```

If I check output on startup I get

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::aboutToQuit() to QNativeWifiEngine::closeHandle()

Exception thrown at 0x749040F8 (KernelBase.dll) in QtTest.exe: 0x000006A6: The binding handle is invalid.
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37926541/1329652) for a complete example and see if it works for you. If it does, you have other problems. If it doesn't, your Qt install is somehow broken/corrupt.

Comment: For my case, the QtTest was already released before download_finished was called.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you are declaring  download_finished() as a slot.

```
class QtTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QtTest(QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void download_finished();
};
```

Comment: The macro Q_OBJECT is declared to class? In my tests its work fine.

Comment: Yes. I've also tried `connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &QtTest::download_finished);`

Comment: Try delete manually the files "Makefile" generated in the build and recompile.

Answer (score -1):

change your definition of download_finished to include the reply;

The signal is; finished(QNetworkReply *reply) so

```
  QtTest::download_finished(QNetworkReply *reply)
  {
     .... etc
```

Make sure to include the parameter in the connect statement.

Comment: If I do that I get error.

QObject::connect: No such signal QNetworkReplyHttpImpl::finished(QNetworkReply *reply) in qttest.cpp:18

Comment: The correct format is; connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

Comment: that doesn't get called either.

Comment: are there error messages in the application output on startup?

Comment: `QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::aboutToQuit() to QNativeWifiEngine::closeHandle()
Exception thrown at 0x749040F8 (KernelBase.dll) in QtTest.exe: 0x000006A6: The binding handle is invalid.`

Comment: That is a separate error, remove that connect or fix it first.

Comment: There's no `QNetworkReply::finished(QNetworkReply*)` signal! You're thinking of `QNetworkAccessManager::finished`, but that's not the right type in this case.

Comment: The documents say that both signals are sent;  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished. But I see that finished() alone should work.